# Python PIL image warping / Affine transformations

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Using Python PIL I want to transform input images in such a way that they seem to be in perspective. Most of the answers I have found are about rotating etc. The images below show one of the effects I am aiming at. Similarly I would like to do this not only from front to back, but also from left to right and vice versa. Another effect I would like is to warp the image in a way that the center is closer and the edges are more distant.

How should I call `im.transform` to get this effect? And why?

Input Image:

[image: Input Image]

Output Effect:

[image: Ouput Image]

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are looking for [perspective transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection). You can do it with Pillow in following way:

```
transformed = image.transform(
    image.size, Image.PERSPECTIVE,
    [
        a0, a1, a2, 
        a3, a4, a5,
        a6, a7
    ],
    Image.BILINEAR
)
```

Where a0-a7 is coefficients used for transformation in this way (from sources, Geometry.c):

```
xout = (a0 * xin + a1 * yin + a2) / (a6 * xin + a7 * yin + 1);
yout = (a3 * xin + a4 * yin + a5) / (a6 * xin + a7 * yin + 1);
```

Comment: Interesting. But what values are required for the effect above?

Comment: Or better, how to translate 3D projections to this 2D input